# Updating Pagination for polling with dataTables object

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using the latest DataTables, however I have not updated my code to use the new API... I am still using the Hungarian notation! I don't mind if answers use the new methods and notation, but I just wanted to frame the context of the question. ;)

I have the potential on a page to have several DataTables, each of them updating every X seconds. For this reason, I basically keep track of my own array of DataTables so that I can call fnDraw on them at the polling interval.

So, on initialize I do something like this:

```
pollObj[0] = $('#myTable').dataTable(options);
```

Then every X seconds, the table gets redrawn thus:

```
pollObj[0].fnDraw(false)
```

The problem is that since the initialization parameters are cached, the DataTable is losing track of its `iDisplayStart` and setting it back to 0 each time. If I'm at page 5 when the polling interval comes around again, it redraws the table back at page 1.

How can I get it to remember my `iDisplayStart`? In other words, how can I modify the `pollObj[i]` after a page change (draw) so that the next time `fnDraw` is called on it, the new value gets used? I found the `fnSettings` method, but there doesn't seem to be a setter. Or is it just `fnSettings()._iDisplayStart = x`?

I've noticed that in `fnDrawCallback`, if I log the oSettings after manually selecting a new page, I get an integer > 0 (for example, 40 when I'm on page 5).

Can I just take that whole of `oSettings` in the fnDrawCallback and apply it back to the cached `pollObj[i]` settings somehow?

(the tricky part will be finding the 'i' at that point, but that's a different story...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the legacy dataTables, then there is a plugin which does a standing redraw , meaning, retain the current page.

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw

Import the plugin and use as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var table = $('.dataTable').dataTable()

      table.fnStandingRedraw();

  } );
```

For DataTables 1.10+ onwards, this is in-built in `draw(false)` method.

Comment: YES! I have absolutely no qualms with using a plug-in that reproduces the behaviour I would have written myself if I was more clever than I am. This worked perfectly. Thanks, faheem!